# Best practice to handle apple push notification when multiple users uses the same device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My app is user specific. multiple users can uses the same device.My application has offline logout functionality. consider that  one of my user (say user 1)logout offline.during that time  my server send notification to the APNS for user1. after some time my device become online. during that time i am not logged in to the app. my question is that while my device is online(when network connection is available)and user1 is logged out will my app receive the push notification from APNS server(those sent for logged out user)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On logout:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];`

On login:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you for sure :

First you have to request a web service when user logout. This web service remove the token of device for the user who is going to logout from server database.

Now you have to add a check (in push notification method at web end which your back end developer is using to send request for push to APNS ) that only push will be send for user who have device token. That's it.

Comment: Pushnotification will work even if your developer will try to send push notification without token.

Comment: @lducool why there are device token then ? You are saying APNS send push notification to everyone .

Comment: Corrected: Pushnotification will *not* work even if your developer will try to send push notification without token. Forgot to write "not"

Comment: @Iducool And it is obvious that when a user try to login then the login webservice request will take device token too in post data as it is a common practice dude.

Comment: @Anuj thank you the above suggestion. my app has multiple users simultaneous login like twitter app. user can change the account by just by selecting the acc in settigns. no need to logout and log in as different user. How to manage this case ( sending notification of both users to the same device will be good ) can you share your openion.

Comment: @Gup see if you change the user from settings in your app it will show details and data for that selected account that means you are virtually logged in with that selected account in your app so the Push notification must come for only that selected user.

Comment: @Gup Now what you can do in this case is maintain a flag column say loggedIn in user table at server db which is by default set to NO or 0 . Now when you select a user from you setting page in app you have to hit a webservice that will take last Selected userid and currently Selected userid to set NO and YES to their respective loggedIn Flag value in db .Now add a check in Push method to send Request to APNS for only users those who has loggedIn Flag value YES.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off receiving push notification programmatically when user logs out of your app.If you did not turn off push notification programmatically it will receive notifications since your device token is registered with server(if your are connected to internet)

Comment: if you delete the app, obviously the push notifications are de-registered. How? I mean what triggers the de-registration?

Answer (score -1):

On logged out you should make one service call that simply wipe out token of this user from webserver.

On successful login of user you should register your device for push notification normally like we are doing. So, again your device token will be registered with server for particular logged in User.